# Firefox add-on to switch a tab's ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: firefox, localization

Some non-English websites show a **dumbed-down/outdated English version** to all visitors whose browsers identifies them as English readers. I usually browse in English but I can read more languages, so I would like to have an easy way to say "Consider me as a Japanese person" for instance.

Requirements:

- Sets the `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` HTTP header to the language of my choice, in all requests sent within that tab.
- Does not change the Firefox menus/etc. Only the content of the web page should use the language, not Firefox itself.
- No need to download "language packs".
- Free, ideally open source.

I tried:

- [Quick Accept-Language Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quick-accept-language-switc/): Good but applies to the whole browser, not [just for one tab](https://github.com/callahad/quick-accept-language-switcher/issues/3).
- [Simple Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/simple-locale-switcher/): It does the opposite of what I want: It only put the Firefox menus/etc in Japanese, but keep sending `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE en-US,en;q=0.5`.
- [TabLang](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tablang/): Crashes at every start.

Comment: Could you list some websites that exhibit this issue?

Comment: @user3169: The Firefox add-ons site redirects based on the `Accept-Language` header, so this could be used for testing. Example: [`https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tablang/`](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tablang/) -- if you have a higher value for German than English, you will get redirected to `https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tablang/`, and if English is higher, to `https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tablang/`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **[Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher)** for that, and am quite satisfied with it. This addon fits all your requirements, also the implicit one: As below screenshots show, you can configure for which URLs a specific language should be used.

[image: menu] [image: config] [image: autoswitch]
<sup>Screenshots: Menu, config, config for auto-switch per URL (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Works fine for me here, though it hasn't been updated in a while. There's a somehow more recent "spin-off" by the name [Quick Locale Switcher 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher2/), but that still carries a very low version number (0.0.1) and obviously is not yet complete (e.g. auto-switching currently does not work). Still worth keeping an eye on in case it catches up – one never knows what time Mozilla decides to drop some compatibility…

**Update:** While the former is no longer available at AMO, the latter still is. I've updated its URL with this edit. It's now at v0.1, but wasn't updated since 10/2018.

Comment: Drawbacks: Last updated in 2013, and some reviews mention it contains spyware.

Comment: I just tried the spin-off. Even after I choose German, https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending still says I am using `en-US,en;q=0.5`. I restarted several times after installing.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I've mentioned it has not been updated in a while. But it works fine for me, so I still can recommend it :) I've never tried the spin-off as a) I'm happy with the original and b) the spin-off still seems to be in Alpha or Beta state (v0.0.1). I've just mentioned it as one day it might be "mature", so then it should be known to exist :)